# Can we write to FAT section for FAT32 file system on Windows 10?

Tags: c, windows, filesystems, fat32

I want to write to FAT/data sections to do something like create files.

Read whole sections is o.k, and write to sections prior to FAT/data section is o.k.

But got error code 5 (access deny) while write to FAT/data sections.

```
// FAT_SEC is retrived from boot sector
FILE* f = fopen("\\\\.\\F:", "rb+");
fseek(f, FAT_SEC * SECTOR_SIZE, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(buffer, 1, SECTOR_SIZE, f);
fflush(f); // Get error here
DWORD err = GetLastError();
```

Comment: What are the "FAT/data" sections? I know of boot sectors, FATs, main directory, and the rest. Please add informations what you tried and what you use: drive parameters, writable and not writable locations. -- Did you try to run the program with administrative rights? It would be too risky to let any user write everywhere.

Comment: @thebusybee What I mean for FAT/data section is two regions to store FAT and the data. The driver is the bulit-in OS driver, I'm not sure if there is any parameter that can be set. Had already test with adminstrative right but got same result.

Comment: I know it would be risky for user to write sections for file system, but I can not find any document to make sure if it is prohibited. If I erase the boot sector, then the os can not recogize the device, then I can write every sections I want.

Comment: If it is prohibited, how can some software to recover the deleted file?

Comment: To learn more about FAT, please consult the freely available ressources. For example, the FAT can start at different offsets, the main directory's offset depends on the size of the FATs and their number, and the rest's offset (where all further information is stored) additionally depends on the size of the main directory.

Comment: Software that recovers deleted files reads a file system on a raw byte basis. Certain patterns are searched and interpreted. You might like to look into the source code of such tools.